# Google Drive Rest APi - how to increase per-user rate limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am using Drive API, and i need to create permissions for a large amount of users, something around 50.

after I am sending the request to google, I am getting a response JSON:

> "error creating permission: **User Rate Limit Exceeded**"

As I saw at Google:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded

they suggested: **"Raise the per-user quota in the Developer Console project."**

but how can I do this?

[maybe in here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqXuk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you can request by clicking the [Apply for a higher quota](https://support.google.com/code/contact/drive_quota?) link. Then fill up the necessary details for the request then Google will process it.

Comment: For the people who's looking for right link: https://console.developers.google.com/project/bionic-path-686/apiui/apiview/drive/quotas login and select your project, increase the quota allowed